# printing out the the text fields and values in array are repeated

Tags: java, arrays

I have repeated values in my array such as `Fiat, 2.3, 2006, Ford, 1.6, 2011`

I'm trying to print out the values like:

```
Name: Fiat
Size: 2.3
Year: 2006

Name: Ford
Size: 1.6
Year: 2011
```

Comment: I've firstly tried using for loops but I obviously I done it wrong. I don't even mind if someone gives me pseudocode so I can code it and come back if I have any problem.

Comment: Post the for loop you tried so people can help you fix it.

Comment: There's no need to downvote questions like this... yes, posters are supposed to do their own research, but obviously the guy is new at programming and needs some help. Mark, I gave you an upvote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to print out an Object array in the given format?

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length-2; i += 3) {
  System.out.println("Name: " + array[i]);
  System.out.println("Size: " + array[i+1]);
  System.out.println("Year: " + array[i+2]);
}
```

Please note that it would really be better to use an object to hold the data on each car, rather than keeping it all in a homogenous array. Something like:

```
class Car {
  String name;
  double size;
  int    year;
  public Car(String _name, double _size, int _year) {
    name = _name; size = _size; year = _year;
  }
}
```

Then to convert your Object array into a list of Cars,

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
for(int i = 0; i < array.length-2; i += 3) {
  cars.add(new Car((String)array[i], (Double)array[i+1], (Integer)array[i+2]);
}
```

This is assuming that you are using an Object array which contains Strings, Doubles, and Integers. If it is a String array,

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
for(int i = 0; i < array.length-2; i += 3) {
  cars.add(new Car((String)array[i], Double.valueOf((String)array[i+1]), Integer.valueOf((String)array[i+2]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try converting this into a method.

Comment: Mark, please note that although this code solves your problem, in the long run you will really be better off if you use an object to hold the data on each car. If you have any problems with the code, post a comment and I will fix it.

Comment: How would I go about doing it in a object? I know I have to create a class with a parameter which takes in the array right? Then I split the array?

Answer (score 2):

Create a class `Car` with three properties `name`, `size` and `modelYear`. Use [String.split()](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0438.html) method to split the `Fiat, 2.3, 2006, Ford, 1.6, 2011` and create `Car` objects.